# Isomorphic JavaScript library using JavaScript modules - Omitting Node.js dependencies in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, isomorphic-javascript

So I'm planning on writing a package which a user will hopefully be able to use on both Node.js and in the browser.

On the Node.js side it will use the `fs` module. This does not exist in the browser perhaps. This could be accomplished with CommonJS with an `if` clause to check which environment the module is in and a simple `require`.

This is not the case with `import` as it is hoisted.

Does anyone have an idea of how to structure the code or the build environment to satisfy both enviroments in the same package?

Comment: Well, if your package does *need* `fs`, then how can it work in the browser? If your package does not need `fs`, then what does it use instead?

Comment: @Bergi I have two functions, one logs to a file (uses `fs`) and one logs to the console. The browser environment would just omit logging to a file and just log to console. The node enviroment would use both functions. That's an example.

Comment: So you mean your browser package would have a different interface than your node package, not containing the file-logging function at all?

Comment: @Bergi Something like this. I'm wondering what others do in this situation. I only know of 3 things. 1) create to npm packages, one for node and one for the browser 2) polyfills (this however does not make sense in this case) 3) use require (node is going towards javascript module though).

Comment: Yes, in that case I think you should make two distinct modules (or one module with two distinct entry points). The nodejs one can re-export the console-logging function from the other file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Stick to ES6 imports

It seems there was an improvement in `import` support in Node.js. [In the docs it says](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules):

> The `--experimental-modules` flag can be used to enable support for
>   ECMAScript modules (ES modules).
>
> Once enabled, Node.js will treat the following as ES modules when
>   passed to node as the initial input, or when referenced by import
>   statements within ES module code:
>
> - Files ending in `.mjs`.
> - Files ending in `.js`, or extensionless files, when the nearest parent `package.json` file contains a top-level field `"type"` with a
>     value of `"module"`.
> - Strings passed in as an argument to `--eval` or `--print`, or piped to node via `STDIN`, with the flag `--input-type=module`.

The second listed approach may be useable with node.js. Simply make sure your librarie's `package.json` contains `"type": "module"` and Node should treat it as a ES6 module instead of CommonJS.

## Conditional import as promise - you will have to wait

Conditional imports are already available in node but not actually supported. They seem to work in browser. And there's a caveat: the imported module is a promise. What that means is that you can have partially isomorphic code as long as you plan your steps well. Knowing that you can do `import("test.js")` in browser and that you can test for `window` means you can write conditions in a smart way and have cross-platform code.

For example you can do:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') const FooPromise = import("foo");
```

But not the opposite. Good luck. Hopefully more support for the es6 dynamic import will come to node.

Comment: That's not the question. The question is how to conditionally import modules based on environment. For example `if (typeof window !== 'undefined') import { Foo } from 'bar'`

Comment: Note that this is possible in commonjs: `if (typeof window !== 'undefined') Foo = require('bar')`

Comment: @slebetman I am aware it is possible in CommonJS, but how does one do this in a ES2015 fashion with `import`? `import` is hoisted so the if clause would not work.

Comment: Oh yeah, I get it now. I faced the same problem as you. Always wanted to have modules that work in node and browser differently. Eg a polyfill for the `fetch` API. Let me do more research